# Java Hangman Game (mostly concerns output)

Tags: java

I am taking an bridging class to Introduction of Java and we have a project that deals with a hangman game. I have most of the code worked out but there is a bug and few problems that I can't seem to resolve.

First, the program displays a disguised word in form of asterisk, then prompts the user for a letter, then the program displays if the user makes a correct/incorrect guess with number of guess made and number of wrong guess made, the letter in the disguised word is replaced with said letter.

For testing purposes, the word use is `html`.

So if I were to guess the letter, the program should output:

**Expected**

```
The disguised word is ****    

Guess a letter: h

Correct. The number of guess made is 1 with 0 wrong
```

**Actual**

```
The disguised word is ****

Guess a letter: h

Incorrect. The number of guess made is 1 with 1 wrong

The disguised word is h***

Guess a letter: m

Incorrect. The number of guess made is 2 with 2 wrong

The disguised word is h*m*

Guess a letter: t

Correct. The number of guess made is 3 with 3 wrong
Good job, you found the secret word which is html
```

The problem I am having is that when I guess the correct letter, the program return as Incorrect as suppose to Correct. In addition, the wrong count is also not working correctly.

We are not allowed to use arrays or string builder as we have yet to be taught and are also reserved for use in project 2.

Here is my code:

**Hangman.java**

```
public class Hangman {

    private String secretWord;
    private String disguisedWord = "";
    private String result;
    private int guesses = 0;
    private int wrongGuess = 0;

    public void setSecretWord(String word) {
        secretWord = word;
    }

    public void setDisguisedWord() {
        for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
            disguisedWord += "*";
        }
    }

    public void guesses() {
        guesses++;
    }

    public boolean guessLetter(char c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < disguisedWord.length(); i++) {
            if (c == secretWord.charAt(i)) {
                disguisedWord = disguisedWord.substring(0, i) + c + disguisedWord.substring(i + 1);
                result = "Correct.";
            } else {
                result = "Incorrect.";
            }
        }

        if (secretWord.equals(disguisedWord)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            wrongGuess++;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getDisguisedWord() {
        return disguisedWord;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public int getGuesses() {
        return guesses;
    }

    public int getWrongGuess() {
        return wrongGuess;
    }

    public String getSecretWord() {
        return secretWord;
    }

}
```

**Game.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

             String word1 = "html";
             String word2 = "css";
             String word3 = "java";

             Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

             Hangman game = new Hangman();
             game.setSecretWord(word1);
             game.setDisguisedWord();

             System.out.println("Let's play a round of hangman.");
             System.out.println("We are playing hangman");

             while (true) {
                     System.out.println("");
                     System.out.println("The disguised word is " + game.getDisguisedWord());
                     System.out.println("Guess a letter:");
                     char guess = kb.next().charAt(0);
                     game.guessCount();
                     boolean isFound = game.guessLetter(guess);
                     if (isFound) {
                             System.out.println(game.getResult() + " No. of guesses made is " + game.getGuesses() + " with " + game.getWrongGuess() + " wrong");
                             System.out.println("Good job, you found the secret word which is " + game.getSecretWord());
                             break;
                     }
                     else {
                             System.out.println(game.getResult() + " No. of guesses made is " + game.getGuesses() + " with " + game.getWrongGuess() + " wrong");
                     }
             }

     }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There is far too much code here for us to be able to answer this question.  Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] (focus on "Minimal" and "Verifiable") that demonstrates your issue.  More info: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of problems, finding count properly, breaking the loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public Hangman {

  private String secretWord;
  private String disguisedWord = "";
  private String result;
  private int guesses = 0;
  private int wrongGuess = 0;

  public void setSecretWord(String word) {
    secretWord = word;
  }

  public void setDisguisedWord() {
    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
      disguisedWord += "*";
    }
  }

  public boolean guessLetter(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < disguisedWord.length(); i++) {
      if (c == secretWord.charAt(i) && disguisedWord.charAt(i) == '*') {
        disguisedWord = disguisedWord.substring(0, i) + c + disguisedWord.substring(i + 1);
        result = "Correct.";
        guesses++;
        return true;
      }
    }
    result = "Incorrect.";
    wrongGuess++;
    return false;
  }

  public String getDisguisedWord() {
    return disguisedWord;
  }

  public String getResult() {
    return result;
  }

  public int getGuesses() {
    return guesses;
  }

  public int getWrongGuess() {
    return wrongGuess;
  }

  public String getSecretWord() {
    return secretWord;
  }

}



public class Game {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word1 = "html";
    String word2 = "css";
    String word3 = "java";

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    Hangman game = new Hangman();
    game.setSecretWord(word1);
    game.setDisguisedWord();

    System.out.println("Let's play a round of hangman.");
    System.out.println("We are playing hangman");

    while (true) {
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("The disguised word is " + game.getDisguisedWord());
      System.out.println("Guess a letter:");
      char guess = kb.next().charAt(0);
      boolean isFound = game.guessLetter(guess);
      if (isFound) {
        System.out.println(game.getResult() + " No. of guesses made is " + game.getGuesses() + " with " + game.getWrongGuess() + " wrong");
        if (game.getDisguisedWord().equals(game.getSecretWord())) {
          System.out.println("Good job, you found the secret word which is " + game.getSecretWord());
          break;
        }
      }
      else {
        System.out.println(game.getResult() + " No. of guesses made is " + game.getGuesses() + " with " + game.getWrongGuess() + " wrong");
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: This code has a bug, so that if there are multiple occurrences of a letter, only the first is replaced.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i tried your code however it does not work when multiple letter occur in the word like if java i entered a, only first a get replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `guessLetter()` method. The first issue is that you overwrite `result` each time a letter is checked, so if it the letter is a match for the first character but not the second, it returns false. The second issue is that you return based on whether the word is now completed, not if the letter was a match. Try this:

```
public boolean guessLetter(char c) {
        boolean foundLetter = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < disguisedWord.length(); i++) {
            if (c == secretWord.charAt(i)) {
                disguisedWord = disguisedWord.substring(0, i) + c + disguisedWord.substring(i + 1);
                foundLetter = true;
            }
        }

        if (foundLetter) {
            result = "Correct.";
            return true;
        } else {
            result = "Incorrect.";
            wrongGuess++;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Also change Game.java to

```
while (true) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("The disguised word is " + game.getDisguisedWord());
            System.out.println("Guess a letter:");
            char guess = kb.next().charAt(0);
            game.guesses();
            boolean isFound = game.guessLetter(guess);
            if (isFound) {
                System.out.println(game.getResult() + " No. of guesses made is " + game.getGuesses() + " with " + game.getWrongGuess() + " wrong");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(game.getResult() + " No. of guesses made is " + game.getGuesses() + " with " + game.getWrongGuess() + " wrong");
            }
            if (game.getSecretWord().equals(game.getDisguisedWord())) {
                System.out.println("Good job, you found the secret word which is " + game.getSecretWord());
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If `guessLetter` returns true, loop in main method breaks, that needs to be fixed as well.

Comment: OP's "actual output" does not reflect the current program. I have a feeling that `Game.java` listed here is not up-to-date since this problem does not occur in the listed "actual output", so I assume it is already fixed by OP.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, your code does not work correctly. The issue is when i entered a correct letter say "h", the program stop immediately with the Good job message appearing.

Comment: @papert1ger I thought this issue had been fixed, see the above edit

Comment: hi my apologies, there are probably some lags in SOF system. Your code works perfectly. cheers!